# WCF error management using WebFaultException - Wrong HttpStatusCode

Tags: wcf, soap, error-handling

I have implemented a simple web service and I want to return appropriate Http Status Error codes depending on the error that occurred in the method being called.

I am using .NET framework 4.7.2 with Visual Studio 2019 and the IIS Express 10 built into Visual Studio for testing at the moment. I am using the Boomerang extension for Chrome to call the service.

I have implemented a `FindPerson` method that takes a name. If the person is not found, or more than one person is found, I want to return a "Not Found" response (404).

I have implemented a simple `ServiceError` class that I am using to throw a `WebFaultException` along with a Not Found error code. When I throw the `WebFaultException` the appropriate fault response is sent to the consumer (I see the details of the problem) **but** the http status is 500 (internal service error) instead of the 404 error I used (and expected to be received)

Here is my simple `FindPerson` method:

```
Private Function FindPerson(ByVal name As String) As Person Implements MyService.FindPerson

    Dim foundPerson As Person = Nothing
    Dim people = GetPeople(name)
    Select Case people.Count
        Case Is > 1
            Throw New WebFaultException(Of ServiceError)(New ServiceError("More than 1 person found with the name provided.", ""), HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        Case Is = 0
            Throw New WebFaultException(Of ServiceError)(New ServiceError("No Person with the name provided was found.", ""), HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        Case Else
            foundPerson = people(0)
    End Select

    Return foundPerson
End Function
```

Here is my ServiceError class:

```
<DataContract>
Public Class ServiceError
    <DataMember>
    Public Property ErrorInfo As String
    <DataMember>
    Public Property ErrorDetails As String
    Public Sub New(ByVal info As String, ByVal details As String)
        Me.ErrorInfo = info
        Me.ErrorDetails = details
    End Sub
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

End Class
```

This is the response I get. Like I said, the details are correct... but the Http Status Error code is 500 instead of 404:

```
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</a:Action>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <s:Code>
                <s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
                <s:Subcode>
                    <s:Value
                        xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2009/WebFault">a:NotFound
                    </s:Value>
                </s:Subcode>
            </s:Code>
            <s:Reason>
                <s:Text xml:lang="en-US">Not Found</s:Text>
            </s:Reason>
            <s:Detail>
                <ServiceError
                    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/My_Web_Service"
                    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <ErrorDetails/>
                    <ErrorInfo>No Person with the name provided was found.</ErrorInfo>
                </ServiceError>
            </s:Detail>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**Edit:**
I found a solution to my problem but it has only made me realize I need to find a better solution.

The solution involved implementing a method called `RaiseWebException` that set the outgoing response status code to the status that was also set in the WebFaultException:

```
Private Sub RaiseWebException(ByVal status As HttpStatusCode, ByVal info As String, ByVal details As String)
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = status
        Throw New WebFaultException(Of ServiceError)(New ServiceError(info, details), HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
End Sub
```

I called the method when I failed to find my person:

```
Private Function FindPerson(ByVal name As String) As Person Implements MyService.FindPerson

  Dim foundPerson As Person = Nothing
  Dim people = GetPeople(name)
  Select Case people.Count
    Case Is > 1
        RaiseWebException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "More than 1 person found with the name provided.", "")
    Case Is = 0
        RaiseWebException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Person with the name provided was found.", "")
    Case Else
        foundPerson = people(0)
  End Select

  Return foundPerson
End Function
```

This works well when calling the method from the browser using Boomerang; however, when I test calling the method in a vb.net consuming test application, I am not seeing the service error details. I am getting the generic 404 error with a generic error message that states that "the endpoint couldn't be reached" instead of "the person wasn't found". This will be confusing for anyone calling the service through a consuming application implemented with .NET

I'm not sure this is the best solution for error management in my service going forward.

I am open to any suggestions on the best practices for error management in .NET web services.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my original question: Set the `OutGoingResponse.StatusCode` to the same status code I used for the `WebFaultException`

The solution involved implementing a method called `RaiseWebException` that set the outgoing response status code to the status that was also set in the WebFaultException:

```
Private Sub RaiseWebException(ByVal status As HttpStatusCode, ByVal info As String, ByVal details As String)
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = status
        Throw New WebFaultException(Of ServiceError)(New ServiceError(info, details), status)
End Sub
```

I call the method when I failed to find my person:

```
Private Function FindPerson(ByVal name As String) As Person Implements MyService.FindPerson

  Dim foundPerson As Person = Nothing
  Dim people = GetPeople(name)
  Select Case people.Count
    Case Is > 1
        RaiseWebException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "More than 1 person found with the name provided.", "")
    Case Is = 0
        RaiseWebException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Person with the name provided was found.", "")
    Case Else
        foundPerson = people(0)
  End Select

  Return foundPerson
End Function
```

This works well when calling the method from the browser using Boomerang; however, when I test calling the method in a vb.net consuming test application, I am not seeing the service error details. I am getting the generic 404 error with a generic error message that states that "the endpoint couldn't be reached" instead of "the person wasn't found". This will be confusing for anyone calling the service through a consuming application implemented with .NET.

So, while this is the answer to my original question/problem, it appears to be inadequate for the overall project. Best of luck to anyone else facing the same thing.